# How-to delete indexes in Google App Engine (Java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is there a way to delete unused indexes in Google App Engine Java application?

The only one way I was able to find is to create an empty Python GAE application and run the following command:

```
appcfg.py vacuum_indexes /path/to/myapp/
```

Is there a more intelligent way?

**Update (16 feb 2011):**

Starting from GAE SDK [1.4.2](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Deleting_Unused_Indexes) it is possible:

```
./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh vacuum_indexes myapp/war
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to vacuum indexes in Java has been added to the GAE SDK 1.4.2. See this blog post for details: http://www.codeonastick.com/?p=95

Comment: Here is official doc: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Deleting_Unused_Indexes

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading that currently this is the only way.  There is an issue in the issue tracker for this support for Java, but its not yet implemented.  http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1893

Comment: Can you provide a proof link, please?

Comment: @Antonio I added the link to my answer